# matlab UpdatePreviewWindowFcn

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

Im using GUIDE to make a matlab GUI which does some video computation.
Using the preview function I can preview the live video from my webcam and do some calculations.

In the MainGUI i use the:
setappdata(hImage,'UpdatePreviewWindowFcn',mypreview_fcn);
to get to a custom preview function which is:

```
function mypreview_fcn(obj,event,himage)

  originalframe=peekdata(vidobj,1);

   while isempty(originalframe)
    originalframe=peekdata(vidobj,1);
   end


   if kk>=1

       [LogResult,y,dist]=QueryArduino;

        if LogResult==1
            kk=kk+1;

            results{kk,1}=originalframe;
            results{kk,2}=measure1;
            results{kk,3}=measure2;
            results{kk,4}=measure3;
            results{kk,5}=measure4;
            results{kk,6}=measure5;
            results{kk,7}=measure7;
            offset=median([results{:,7}]);
            offset=measure2-measure3;


        end
  end
  set(himage,'CData',originalframe);

  end
```

I would like to pass the result matrix to a table in the MainGUI
How can I access the GUI table;

Comment: you mean you want to access `results` inside `MainGUI`?

Comment: I  have a constructed a table with guide inside the MainGUI that i would like to populate with the results.
So basically yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using [getappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html?searchHighlight=getappdata) to pass all the data you want inside `MainGUI` and populate the table. Actually I don't understand why you would use `setappdata` to call a function.

For instance, in the function `mypreview_fcn` you coudl write something like this right before the end of the function:

```
setappdata(0,'MyData',results);
```

and then in `MainGUI` use `getappdata`:

```
TableData = getappdata(0,'MyData');
set(HandletoTable,'Data',TableData);
```

An alternative (and better approach I think) to `getappdata` would be to assign an output argument to the function `mypreview_fcn` so that when you call it from `mainGUI` the variable `results` is recognized inside `mainGUI` and you can populate the table simply using

```
set(HandletoTable,'Data',results);
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: Well that would be great but as far as I know the preview function works as described here [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/previewing-data.html#f11-76693)

Comment: Ah ok I thought that was a function you had created and not one created by GUIDE.

Comment: Well that would be great but as far as I know the preview function works as described here [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/previewing-data.html#f11-76693)
As the video is running this loop (ie mypreview_fcn) is constantly called until a 'stop preview button' is pushed.

If I use the 'setappdata' solution the 'getappdata' will bever be called in the 'MainGUI' because 'mypreview_fcn' keeps running
So I need to find a way to interact directly to the 'handle.table_results' from inside  'mypreview_fcn'